# c# Cafe Manager Application That requires login and runs at startup

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create an application (Windows Form) for Internet Cafe Managment that runs at startup of each client and asks for login credentials. I am running the server application at my counter system. I have the database in Server and clients can access it through WCF application.
My problem is how to get it to run at system startup and only allow people to use the system after entering the right credentials. No other activities should take place without entering credentials.and also cannot be closed.

Comment: Running the app at startup is easy, there are several standard ways to do it by adding a key to the registry. Can be done by your installer.

You can make a secure wcf service so all service calls will be authenticated. Btw, ifserver and clients are all in the same network you can use windows authentication thus no need to make your own security system. As for making the app impossible to close this is probably hard. I even saw ATMs with naked windows screen :-)

Comment: @ElDog On the contrary, the "standard" way to get an app to run at startup is to add it to the "Startup" folder. There's one for each individual user, and there is one for "All Users". Editing the registry is *not* the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you will be reinventing the wheel (this has been solved many times) but if you really want to roll your own here are some things to look at:

- look at creating a [replacement Windows shell](http://pravin.paratey.com/posts/deeshell) (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728444) too)
- Running an app [at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089601)
- Running [at logon](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/474092/Run-Csharp-application-on-Windows-startup-Windows)
- Setting of Winforms [app to system modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170738) (use the form to dominate the screen until auth happens)

Your question is broad and there are many ways to achieve what you're looking for. Some can be clean and complex while others will be dirty hacks (system modal form) but simpler to implement.

Comment: The links you provided were useful. I used the method of add it to startup folder. I am doing the windows application in WPF. I found code to disable the key combinations like Alt+ F4 and others. Thank you once again and I understand my question was not precise.